# Quick breads in foil pans

Tags: baking, bread

When cooking quick breads in foil pans should they be placed on a cookie sheet or set on oven rack?

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason you have to put foil pans on a tray, they can be put directly on the rack if you like. There's no reason not to either, it's a matter of convenience. If you want a scientific answer a tray will interfere with air circulation a little, but not enough it makes a real difference to baking times or the end result.

Using a tray can be a good idea if the pans are too flexible to handle easily, and also if you are baking many of them at once putting many on one tray makes it faster to get them in and out.

Answer (score 2):

## It doesn't matter provided the cookie sheet is metal

Using a metal baking sheet will not make a material difference in baking time or results from putting foil pans directly on the oven rack. Other materials, such as glass or silicone, can make a significant difference however.

Comment: I've only used aluminum trays ... do dark metal trays behave differently?  (I mention it because cake and brownie mixes often have an adjustment for them)